# Some book suggestions for performance tuning

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I am in the process of improving performance on our database application. While I am not a DBA, I am pretty comfortable with SQL. I am after a book that can help me understand how queries written in different ways affect performance and also   understanding things like table scans, indexes  an statistics.

I don't just want to blindly add everything the tuning advisor says so I am looking for the knowledge required to assess these recommendations in the context our environment and how to fully utilise the tools available.  I am working with MSSQL2008+ so a book the utilises this environment specific would be good.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like Kalen Delaney's internals book:

- [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Internals](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=12967)

I also like the Brent Ozar / Christian Bolton book:

- [Professional SQL Server 2008 Internals and Troubleshooting](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-SQL-Server-2008-Internals-and-Troubleshooting.productCd-0470484284.html)

For T-SQL tuning, you can't get much a better T-SQL wizard than Itzik Ben-Gan:

- [Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Programming](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=12805)
- [Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Querying](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=12804)

And query tuning overall, Grant Fritchey and Sajal Dam:

- [SQL Server 2008 Query Performance Tuning Distilled](http://www.apress.com/9781430219026)

There are also some interesting solutions and opinions presented in various chapters in the two MVP Deep Dives titles (from which all proceeds go to two charities, War Child and Operation Smile):

- [SQL Server MVP Deep Dives Volume 1](http://manning.com/nielsen/) (War Child)
- [SQL Server MVP Deep Dives Volume 2](http://manning.com/delaney/) (Operation Smile)

And a couple of the Red Gate titles @Kev left out, but which are both excellent:

- [Inside the SQL Server Query Optimizer](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/books/71564) (Ben Nevarez)
- [Troubleshooting SQL Server: A Guide for the Accidental DBA](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/books/76296/) (Jonathan Kehayias / Ted Kreuger)

Comment: +1.  The only one I'd add to that is Grant Fritchey's *SQL Server 2008 Query Performance Tuning Distilled*.

Comment: By all means, please do.

Comment: +1 This is a solid DBA bundle for perf tuning! I am so bookmarking this!

Answer (score 5):

Red Gate have a good [set of books](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Books/) about performance and tuning, specifically:

- [Performance Tuning with SQL Server Dynamic Management Views](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/books/70486/)
- [SQL Server Execution Plans](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/books/65831/)
- [Defensive Database Programming](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/books/69647/)

Most of these are available as free downloadable PDFs

Comment: Thank you, I do love the word "free". How would these compare to a paid book? I should have added I am happy to pay what is needed for a good book.

Comment: You can pay for a paper copy :) I find these books very good!

Comment: @tyrongower it depends on whether you are comfortable with e-books or not. Personally I like to hold a physical book in my hand. But they do have a good series of excellent books by reputable authors.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm the same way.  I just need a physical book.  Not much into e-readers either.

Answer (score 2):

[Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2005: Query Tuning and Optimization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735621969) by Kalen Delaney is one of the best books I have read. Although the title of the book is on SQL Server 2005 this applies to SQL Server 2008 or 2008 R2.